# If $f$ is has period $\omega$ and a pole at $z_0$, prove that $f$ has a pole at $z_0+\omega$.

Tags: complex-analysis, periodic-functions

How do I show if $f$ is a meromorphic function with period $\omega$ and a pole at $z_0$, then $z_0+\omega$ is also a pole of $f$ with the same multiplicity and residue?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $\epsilon>0$ is small enough to contain only one pole of $f$, we follow Cauchy...
$$\oint_{|z_0+\omega-z|=\epsilon} \frac{f(z)}{z-(z_0 + \omega)}\mathrm{d}z = \oint_{|z_0-y|=\epsilon} \frac{f(y+\omega)}{y-z_0}\mathrm{d}y = \oint_{|z_0-y|=\epsilon} \frac{f(y)}{y-z_0}\mathrm{d}y$$ where we have used the substitution $y = z-\omega$.  This last integral should look pretty familiar.

Comment: So then you can use Cauchy's integral formula. But how is that relevant to the question of proving the poles have the same multiplicity?

Comment: Cauchy's integral formula applies to derivatives.  The leading constant (suppressed in the above) changes and the power of the denominator changes.  Neither change prevents the manipulations shown.  This is sufficient.  (What happens to multiple poles and multiple roots under (repeated) differentiation?)